# Tablesorter Scroller bootstrap not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

I am trying to use Tablesorter and the scroller widget.  I just cant seem to get it right.  It seems that bootstrap.css affects the resizing of the fixed header.

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/4FMRh/6/) of the problem.  And if we do not have bootstrap.css then it will work as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4FMRh/5/)

Here is the Tablesorter Code:

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
widthFixed : true,
showProcessing: true,
headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}',
widgets: [  'zebra',  'scroller' ],
widgetOptions : {
  scroller_height : 300,
  scroller_barWidth : 17,
  scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
  scroller_idPrefix : 's_'
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="span12 hidden-phone">
            <table class="tablesorter">
<caption>Student Grades</caption>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Major</th><th>Sex</th><th>English</th><th>Japanese</th><th>Calculus</th><th class="filter-false sorter-false">Geometry</th></tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Major</th><th>Sex</th><th>English</th><th>Japanese</th><th>Calculus</th><th>Geometry</th></tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>Student01</td><td>Languages</td><td>male</td><td>80</td><td>70</td><td>75</td><td>80</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student02</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>90</td><td>88</td><td>100</td><td>90</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student03</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>85</td><td>95</td><td>80</td><td>85</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Student04</td><td>Languages</td><td>male</td><td>60</td><td>55</td><td>100</td><td>100</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo is missing the `theme.bootstrap.css` file and a few options (theme & uitheme widget; [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4FMRh/7/))

```
$(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
    theme: 'bootstrap', // set bootstrap theme
    widthFixed: true,
    showProcessing: true,
    headerTemplate: '{content} {icon}',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'uitheme', 'scroller'], // include uitheme widget
    widgetOptions: {
        scroller_height: 300,
        scroller_barWidth: 17,
        scroller_jumpToHeader: true,
        scroller_idPrefix: 's_'
    }
});
```

Comment: This works in Chrome but Not in FF 23.0.1 currently.  Will update when it changes.

Comment: There was a bug in the scoller plugin.  Line 206: should be $hdr.width($tbl.innerWidth()).parent().width($tbl.innerWidth());  Now that it is fixed the system works great!

Comment: I didn't notice any difference in the results with the above code you shared. Is the problem in a specific browser?

Comment: No the problem is with the scroller plugin [here](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/js/widgets/widget-scroller.js)

Comment: Could you please open an issue... I'll try to get to it when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The above response does not work for me (Firefox 29) on the other hand the change to scroller.js in the comments by r0n22 does.

> There was a bug in the scoller plugin. Line 206: should be
>   $hdr.width($tbl.innerWidth()).parent().width($tbl.innerWidth()); Now
>   that it is fixed the system works great!